# Underline in Persian keyboard

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, keyboard-layout

I'm trying to add underline between two word in Persian.

In English , <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>-</kbd> combination works well and I can type underline character well, like this:

> Ask_Ubuntu

But in Persian this keys combination not work. And when I press <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>-</kbd> instead of underline typing, the letters stretch like this:

> اسکـاوبونتو

So, how can I use underline in Persian language?

Comment: That's the thing I was looking for (stretching Persian words) :-D +1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try <kbd>Right Alt</kbd> + <kbd>-</kbd> instead.

شس _ شس